# Loading page dynamically from database via id in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to load a page dynamically based on the database results however I have no idea how to implement this into codeigniter.

I have got a controller:

```
function history()
{
//here is code that gets all rows in database where uid = myid
}
```

Now in the view for this controller I would like to have a link for each of these rows that will open say `website.com/page/history?fid=myuniquestring` however where I am getting is stuck is how exactly I can load up this page and have the controller get the string. And then do a database query and load a different view if the string exsists, and also retrieve that string.

So something like:

```
function history$somestring()
{
    if($somestring){
    //I will load a different view and pass $somestring into it
    } else {
    //here is code that gets all rows in database where uid = myid
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how I can detect if $somestring is at the end of the url for this controller and then be able to work with it if it exists.

Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if your url is :

```
http://base_url/controller/history/1
```

Say, 1 be the id, then you retrieve the id as follows:

```
function history(){
    if( $this->uri->segment(3) ){ #if you get an id in the third segment of the url
        // load your page here
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3); #get the id from the url and load the page
    }else{
         //here is code that gets all rows in database where uid = myid and load the listing view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generate urls like `website.com/page/history/myuniquestring` and then declare controller action as:

```
function history($somestring)
{
    if($somestring){
       //I will load a different view and pass $somestring into it
    } else {
       //here is code that gets all rows in database where uid = myid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can just expect this from your URI segments, I'm going to give a very generic example. Below, we have a controller function that takes two optional arguments from the given URI, a string, and an ID:

```
public function history($string = NULL, $uid = NULL)
{
    $viewData = array('uid' => NULL, 'string' => NULL);
    $viewName = 'default';

    if ($string !== NULL) {
           $vieData['string'] = $string;
           $viewName = 'test_one';
    }

    if ($uid !== NULL) {
           $viewData['uid'] = $uid;
    }

    $this->load->view($viewName, $viewData);
}
```

The actual URL would be something like:

```
example.com/history/somestring/123
```

You then know clearly both in your controller and view which, if any were set (perhaps you need to load a model and do a query if a string is passed, etc.

You could also do this in an `if / else if / else` block if that made more sense, I couldn't quite tell what you were trying to put together from your example. Just be careful to deal with none, one or both values being passed.

The more efficient version of that function is:

```
public function history($string = NULL, $uid = NULL)
{
    if ($string !== NULL):
         $viewName = 'test_one';
         // load a model? do a query?
    else:
         $viewName = 'default';
    endif;
    // Make sure to also deal with neither being set - this is just example code
    $this->load->view($viewName, array('string' => $string, 'uid' => $uid));
}
```

The expanded version just does a simpler job at illustrating how segments work. You can also examine the given URI directly using the [CI URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) (`segment()` being the most common method). Using that to see if a given segment was passed, you don't have to set default arguments in the controller method.

As I said, a bunch of ways of going about it :)